# How to solve this error in Bash while looping elements in directory?

Tags: bash

So here is my code

```
tree() {
    shopt -s nullglob 
    cd "$1" || exit
    debt=$2
    cdebt=$3
    pl="----"
    for elem in *; do
       # code
    done
    shopt -u nullglob 
}
```

Can anyone help me with this i haven't been able to solve it for hours
Any helps or hints are greatly appreciated

Comment: "judezevo drevo" this is the base directory?

Comment: Add `#!/bin/bash` to the top of your script and paste it into [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)  -- all will become clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try `bash -x script.sh` to debug your code and find the wrong logicality.

You should add double quotes to around your parameter prevent that some directory or file name which included blank space will identify to more than one parameter.

In your code, you should change `$elem` to `"$elem"`, `$PWD` to `"$PWD"`, `$dir` to `"$dir"`.

Comment: Good eyes, even though there are a number of duplicates, worthy of the vote for the keen eye.

Comment: I did what u said and it helped, yet there is one problem left,  this is supposed to be the starting home directory /home/test/tests/gozd/judezevo drevo  the only issue is the initial directory since it reads it as  /home/test/tests/gozd/judezevo instead of  /home/test/tests/gozd/judezevo drevo

Comment: @Majora-NK `printf "DIR   %s\n" "$dir";` had fixed this line?

Comment: And thanks for @DavidC.Rankin who had gave the good advice to clear the code.